# Ajax file upload using jquery in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, asyncfileupload

I have to enter different data in a view which includes a partial view for file upload. I want to achieve uploading file to database without loosing other data in my view. ie. i need to upload a file to database in a byte stream using jquery. How can i achieve this??
Thanks for all help in prior.

Answer (score 0):

I would base64 encode the image, and post it to the server that could decode the base64 into a byte blob for the database. That would probably be the path of least pain, both client and server side.

Comment: I would like to know how to upload the file using jquery?

Comment: Upload the file to the database?